# Which of Marvel's mortals can survive a nuclear bomb?

Tags: marvel

It's popularly known that Wolverine has survived a nuclear bomb blast. And I just learned that Hulk has been directly hit by a nuclear bomb.

Other than these two, how many of Marvel's mortals have survived a nuclear bomb blast, or can survive a nuclear bomb blast?

Comment: Anyone, if they use a fridge.

Comment: @b_jonas How? I am unable to see even a joke here...

Comment: He's talking about [this fridge](http://www.bestinfographics.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/how-indiana-jones-survived-a-nuclear-bomb-in-a-fridge.png).

Comment: @SachinShekhar - http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160206/nuke-the-fridge

Comment: The problem here is that too many of the characters powers flux depending on the writer. In Days of Future Past, Wolverine died and did not regenerate after being hit by a blast from a sentinel.

Comment: @Wikis I have never seen that before, that is amazing

Comment: "Mortal" in the Marvel Universe is also a relative term.  The have more comic book deaths (i.e. ones that don't stick) than you can shake an Ultimate Nullifier at.

Comment: Agreed with @Monty129 - Wolverine is practically immortal, especially with certain writers.  Is Sentry mortal? Thor is technically immortal, or at least eternal - but he isn't invulnerable.  I'm not entirely sure he would survive a proper nuclear blast without a fridge around.

Comment: @joshbirk I think Thor, as with all the Asgardians and most of the other "gods" in the Marvel Universe are the "Immortal until killed" kind of immortal.  Thor is fated to die in Ragnarok, Hercules (who is actually a demigod) has died, Sentry is dead...until he's not anymore.

Comment: I've voted to close. As it stands it's far too broad. If it was "who's survived a nuke" it would be OK but there are over 500 marvel characters and at least half could *possibly* survive under the right circumstance.

Comment: The question should say *something* about proximity to Ground Zero. Practically anyone can survive a nuclear blast with only minor injuries, given some distance. (Thousands did in Japan in 1945).

Comment: Wow. I saw this and was like "this doesn't seem like a closeworthy question". Then I read the comments and I saw the problem, so I went to VTC. Then I realized I had already done so...yesterday. /facepalm. Where has my mind gone?

Comment: @Wikis What is this Kingdom of the Crystal Skull mentioned in the image?

Comment: Technically Iron man did too in Avengers, although the blast didn't hit him. OP didn't specify if character had to survive it directly or circumstances to which one can survive a nuclear bomb blast.

Comment: @Jared By your definition, grandparents of almost every guy have survived 1945 atom bombs?

Comment: @SachinShekhar - if they were in Nagasaki and/or Hiroshima, yes. Iron Man was meters from the blast radius as he fell through the portal, he deserves a special mention in this regard imo.

Comment: @Jared No, he wasn't meters from blast radius. He saw entire Chitauri starship fleet in one view.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - re-watch the scene again, it *was* meters away.

Comment: @Jared Apply common sense, my friend. He saw the bomb hitting Chitauri fleet. How can you see a big structure in one view if you are near?

Comment: @SachinShekhar - I am talking about the blast wave here not the initial explosion. The blast wave from the nuke/Chitauri ship was meters away from Tony/Iron Man as he fell through the portal wormhole. The only difference between that scene and *The Wolverine* scene, was that Logan had no escape from the blast wave, where as Tony did.  But imo that still means in my books that he survived a nuclear explosion. Just a different way than I guess traditionally surviving by special powers or shields etc, if you like...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### Invulnerability or regeneration powerful enough to allow one to survive a nuclear attack of any real magnitude is fairly uncommon in the Marvel Universe, but the biggest of the big guns of the Marvel Universe can survive, if barely, a standard ten megaton nuke; though probably not under optimal conditions.

NOTE: A nuclear device utilized under optimal conditions will likely kill almost everyone on this list. When confronted by nukes in most stories, they are usually smaller, not configured properly, too far away or some other aspect which allows the reader and the character enough of a possibility of survival to allow suspension of belief. (See: Indiana Jones and the Refrigerator of Nuclear Resistance)

This is most assuredly an incomplete list: Through sheer toughness (armored skin, invulnerability, super-fast regeneration, or some combination):

**The Hulk (the Abomination and likely the Red Hulk):**

- His sheer toughness and regenerative ability has allowed him to survive nuclear blasts over his entire history.
- He is one of the few mortals in the Marvel Universe capable of surviving a nuclear blast without aid of technology of any kind. (This would probably include his son, Skar who has all of his physical characteristics and many of his mother's as well.)

**Blue Marvel:**

- One of the most powerful of the Superman-analog in the Marvel Universe, his powers have almost no equal on Marvel Earth-616, he has defeated the entire team of Avengers without breaking a sweat and has the invulnerability to survive a nuclear attack.
- Blue Marvel is likely one of the most powerful mortals on Marvel Earth-616.

**Thor:**

- Technically, mortal, but extremely long-lived thanks to the Golden Apples of Idunn. His superhuman strength, a testament to his mother, Gaia, and his Asgardian physiology from his father, gives him a level of invulnerability far beyond most Asgardians.
- With the energy manipulating powers of Mjolnir, Thor could survive common nuclear attacks with difficulty. He is likely tough enough to survive one even without Mjolnir energy manipulating powers, but just barely. I would recommend he get under cover like everyone else.

**The Sentry:**

- His powers, barely understood, make him one of the mightiest mortals on Marvel Earth-616. He can survive nuclear attacks because he believes he can. It's that simple.
- When he is in his right mind, he draws from a well of nearly inexhaustible energy, making him as powerful as he needs to be.

**The Juggernaut: Cain Marko**

- It is theorized that Cain Marko was, for all intents and purposes, indestructible as long as he was the Avatar of Cyttorak.
- In no other ways superhuman, the powers he gained while using the Gem of Cyttorak made him able to fight and win against nearly any other superhuman on Marvel Earth.
- His level of invulnerability was tested in struggles against the X-men and Avengers on numerous occasions.

**The Juggernaut: Colossus**

- With the superhuman durability of his osmium skin (which might not make him quite tough enough to survive a nuke at close range) coupled with the power gained by being an Avatar of Cyttorak, Juggernaut Colossus is arguably one of the most indestructible beings on the Marvel Earth-616.
- Only beings of comparable power or possessing high-order energy manipulation or magic are even able to slow him down, let alone stop him. The energy of a nuclear weapon likely pales in comparison to his avatar-enhanced form.

**Gladiator:**

- A cosmic hero (and another Superman-analog), but mortal as far as we know, Gladiator is imbued with incredible power. Easily able to best most of the Marvel Earth powerhouses, he is a one-man army.
- His only weakness is his need to maintain his concentration to utilize is incredible abilities. Awake and aware of the threat, Gladiator is an easy candidate for survival.

**Hyperion:**

- Yet another Superman-analog, he is a being whose durability would allow him to survive, just barely a nuclear strike.
- He would also be immune to the radiation and atomic particulate fallout. He would not enjoy the experience.

#### Utilizing some combination of their superhuman abilities, and/or coupled with their sheer intellect, these characters may have a chance of surviving a nuclear attack.

**Magneto: Master of Magnetism**

- Utilizing his mastery of the fundamental forces of magnetism, Magneto has managed to create force barriers sufficiently strong to blunt the effects of nuclear attack on at least one occasion.
- He would likely utilize surrounding metallic materials to increase his shielding against the heat blast of the initial explosion.
- This would likely tax him to the limits of his ability but he would more than likely survive, battered but alive. He would need to be utilizing his power to repel both radiation and particulate matter.

**Apocalypse:**

- With his powers of personal molecular control, he can alter his durability and resistance to injury enough to survive a nuclear strike.
- He would probably not enjoy it and would likely utilize mass from the environment to ablate the damage from affecting him, the same way he can utilize that mass to change his size.
- Given his level of molecular control, neither radiation nor fallout would mean anything to him.

**Jean Grey: As Dark Phoenix**

- In her Dark Phoenix form, Grey flew through a star causing the star to supernova. She was unaffected.
- Her other incarnations of the Phoenix were significantly less powerful, but the Phoenix force was capable of battling Galactus to a stand-still, so they may also be powerful enough to survive a nuclear attack, if just barely.

**Susan Storm:**

- I would grant her the ability to survive only if she were with Mr. Fantastic and he were utilizing his fantastic genius to augment her abilities in some fashion.
- Her force fields while amazing and powerful have a feedback component which means depending on the force attacking them, she feels a stress or strain while defending against that force.
- I don't see her being able to withstand a nuclear attack without technological assistance, getting under cover, or some other means of blunting the raw force of the nuke. She has never shown such capacity even when she was free of psychological restraints in her Malice identity.

#### Of the Avengers lineups over the last 50 years, the following could make an effective attempt at surviving a nuclear blast.

**Hercules:** functionally immortal, super tough, damage resistant

**Ms. Marvel:** massive energy manipulation, but not likely powerful enough to survive a nuke at close range.

**The Vision:** assuming he was hardened against the EMP, his intangibility should make him relatively resistant to the blast and effects of the nuke.

**Wonder Man:** Unliving ionic energy, super durable, even if destroyed, he can reform himself over time.

**Jack of Hearts:** Unliving energy, cannot be destroyed, functionally immortal

**Starbrand:** Capable of manipulating massive energies directed by the will.

**Quasar:** Extreme energy manipulation, hard light constructs

**Captain Universe:** Extreme energy manipulation

#### Most powerful of known heroic mutants:

**Vulcan:** A Superman-analog, he was capable of vast energy manipulations and was capable of surviving under almost any conditions.

**Shadowcat:** It is unclear how long she could maintain her phased state, but while phased she was invulnerable to most forms of physical or energy attack. If she does not actually need to breathe the nuke would be unable to harm her.

**Hope Summers:** The ability to replicate or duplicate any mutant power she has experienced.

**Elixir:** Capable of matter alteration, altering living organisms and raising the dead

Comment: Hope's repitoire of known mutants doesn't include anyone who could survive a nuke, unless you're adding Cable/Stryfe/X-man to the list.  (And Vulcan's closer to green lantern than Supes, fwiw.)

Comment: Lots of immortals in this list. Good answer though.

Comment: Almost everyone on this list started their lives as a mortal being. The only known semi-immortals would be Thor, Hercules, Wonder Man and Captain Universe (who is technically just a container of cosmic energy).

Comment: If we're considering energy or matter manipulation (rightfully so), I would think Scarlet Witch would be a contender at least.

Comment: The reason I didn't include her was the historic unreliability of her powers.

Comment: great answer there are lots of `Superman-analog`s in the list. What are Superman-analogs?

Comment: Forgotten from this list are of course The Silver Surfer with his cosmic energy. Scarlet Witch with reality manipulation powers. Also Longshot is a possibility since There is a chance that debris would fly around him that would construct the make up of a fridge, damn luck power.

Comment: And as noted in the comments, the Scarlet Witch's powers have been entirely too unreliable despite their potential capabilities. The Silver Surfer hardly counts as mortal, and with the Power Cosmic has little to fear from a nuclear weapons since he surfs over the surface of stars. Longshot's power is also a bit unreliable for him to be risking his life against a nuclear weapon not going off. Because that is the only way he survives. The nuke simply doesn't work. (Which is well within his capabilities) but he isn't surviving the nuke, he is defusing it.

Comment: Hope Summers can only mimmick the powers of those near hear.

Comment: It is disbelief which is suspended.

Comment: @SMR: Superman-analogs are what in the comic PS238 is referred to as "FISS". People who possess "Flight, Invulnerability, Strength, Speed".  http://ps238.nodwick.com/comic/12072006/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS238

Comment: I think you meant to say, Captain Marvel not Ms. Marvel.

Answer (score 11):

Off the top of my head there's at least half a dozen Marvel **Mortals** who could (theoretically) survive a nuke from ground zero;

- [Sue Richards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invisible_Woman) (with her shield)
- [The Juggernaut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juggernaut_%28comics%29#Powers_and_abilities) (invulnerable)
- [Kitty Pryde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitty_Pryde) (can become intangible)
- [Dr Strange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Strange#Powers_and_abilities) (magical shield)
- [Magneto](http://www.comicvine.com/forums/gen-discussion-1/telekinetic-force-field-and-magnetos-shield-417544/) (psychic shield)
- [Colossus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus_%28comics%29#Powers_and_abilities) (can turn into metal capable of resisting heat)
- [Jean Grey](https://marvel.com/universe/Phoenix_%28Jean_Grey%29) (as Dark Phoenix - Infinitely powerful psionic shield)

etc etc.

I'm sure someone will be along shortly with an in-canon list of nukes and who's survived them.

Comment: I would debate Magneto based on physics alone, but who am I kidding?

Comment: @joshbirk - I'm fairly sure that he's withstood at least one nuclear explosion before.

Comment: Yeah, I actually don't disagree with his inclusion.  He is, or is nearly, and Omega-level mutant to whom the laws of physics don't entirely apply.  However in the real world being able to control the magnetic field would do very little to the heat wave of a thermonuclear blast.  But hey, I guess he's also the most likely to find a lead-lined fridge...or I suppose quickly arrange a mountain to take the blast...

Comment: Which reminds, Jean Grey would probably apply as well.  Or at least Dark Phoenix.

Comment: @joshbirk - I've added her to the list.

Answer (score 5):

The heat of a nuke is between 50 and 150 million degrees Fahrenheit.

http://forums.introversion.co.uk/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=44646

Colossus can only resist temperatures of upto  9000º F.

> His armored form can withstand ballistic penetration as well as
>   temperature extremes from 70º above absolute zero (-390º F) to
>   approximately 9000º F.
>
> More on Marvel.com:
>   [http://marvel.com/universe/Colossus_(Piotr_Rasputin)#ixzz32agSYPJ5](http://marvel.com/universe/Colossus_%28Piotr_Rasputin%29#ixzz32agSYPJ5)

http://marvel.com/universe/Colossus_%28Piotr_Rasputin%29

When listing Magneto, Sue Storm etc, etc I think you are overlooking one very important aspect of a nuke, radiation. None of these have accelerated healing nor as they immune to toxins or radiation. The fallout would be a major issue. I'm not sure if Sue's Shield could withstand a nuke but she would need to maintain it for some time to avoid the radiation from the fallout. I don't think Magneto's shield could survive a hit, I read Cyclops almost managed to break it and his optic blasts are nowhere near nuke level. Namor is said to have taken nukes. All these would survive with ease :

Adam Warlock - High energy manipulation
Beta Ray Bill - Basically has Thor's powers
Deadpool - accelerated healing, cannot die
Firestar - extreme energy absorption and manipulation
Ghost Rider - invulnerable to everything but certain types of magic
Havok - As his powers are cosmic energy he is resistant to most forms of energy
Kid Gladiator - Although like his father he is prone to certain forms of radiation he would survive
Ronan the Accuser - his hammer has vast energy manipulation powers
Spectrum - can transform herself into any form of energy
Thanos - very high durability, has survived a black hole with ease, cannot die, reforms
Tyrant - Former herald of Galactus who easily dealt with an amped Thanos. Second to Galactus in terms of cosmic power, killed by the ultimate nulifier.

A-Bomb, Lyra, Red She Hulk, She-Hulk. All gamma powered, gamma is more powerful than nuclear power so they would survive.

> Charles Q. Choi from LiveScience.com further explains that unlike the
>   Incredible Hulk, gamma rays are not green; existing as they do beyond
>   the visible spectrum, gamma rays have no color at all that we can
>   describe. He also explains that gamma rays are so powerful (the
>   highest form of light and 10,000 times more powerful than visible
>   light) that they can even create matter- a possible explanation for
>   the increased mass that Bruce Banner takes on during transformations.
>   "Just as the Incredible Hulk "is the strongest one there is," as he
>   says himself, so too are gamma ray bursts the most powerful explosions
>   known."
>
> http://www.hotdog.hu/engcor/comic-characters/incredible-hulk

Comment: Deadpool? He'd be vaporised in a nanosecond...

Comment: "Deadpool has established a relationship with the personification of Death and as a result has been cursed by Thanos, to be unable to die." Also read the sections about his healing powers. http://marvel.wikia.com/Deadpool_%28Wade_Wilson%29

Comment: Notwithstanding that that makes no sense, what mechanism would prevent him from being turned into a hot plasma then?

Comment: He would turn into hot plasma but regenerate very quickly. He has a supernatural curse which prevents him from dying AND his headlong factor is significantly more potent than Wolverine's. Deadpool has survived being liquefied from the waist up.

Comment: He'd be turned into a plasma and spread over an area the size of a small town and you're expecting him to "regenerate quickly"?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13381/could-wolverine-survive-a-nuclear-bomb

Comment: Here's Deadpool surviving a nuke. About 1/4 of the way down.

http://www.comicvine.com/deadpool/4005-7606/forums/respect-deadpool-654202/

Answer (score 0):

Silver Surfer can fly through stars unaffected.
Also, Nova and Firelord (they are basically stars in humanoid form) among possibly other heralds of Galactus.

Human Torch, Nova, and Binary all have flame-type forms that would make them likely to survive.

Also, Captain Marvel (the light-transforming one) could shift to a form a light wave that might be moved but not harmed: x-rays, maybe?)

I agree with most of the others listed above.

Oh, also Franklin Richards can manipulate reality so, no problem so long as he knows it is coming.

Also molecule man if he had time or prior knowledge could manipulate the physical world enough to save himself (even before he had his "block" on manipulating organic matter removed by the Beyonder).

Answer (score -1):

And Genis-Vell too.
He is one of the most powerful Cosmic Heroes.

Comment: A cursory search would suggest that he's the son of an eternal and hence not a marvel mortal. He's at least half-immortal.

Comment: A cursory search on the dictionnary would have helped you to understand the meaning of the word "mortal":
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mortal

subject to death; having a transitory life:
all mortal creatures.

Genis-Vell ability to survive a nuclear bomb belongs to his gear as his Nega-bands are allowing him to shield himself of the destruction caused by a bomb or to redirect the energy.