# How strong is Loki? Can he be destroyed by a nuclear explosion?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, loki

In the Avengers movie, humans tried to kill Loki and the Chitauri by launching a nuclear weapon. However, would this nuclear weapon actually have killed Loki?

Comment: To be fair, I don't think SHIELD or the World Security Council actually had any idea of whether or not the nuclear missile would be enough. It was just the strongest thing they had in their arsenal, and were hoping that it would be enough.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52926/which-of-marvels-mortals-can-survive-a-nuclear-bomb

Comment: As @phantom42 points out, I don't necessarily think the nuke was directed at Loki in particular, merely a general deterrent to the entire invading force of Ch'tauri.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Yes, a nuke would certainly kill Loki.

Within the [Earth-19999](http://marvel.wikia.com/Earth-199999) movie universe, Loki's powers would be insufficient to resist a nuclear blast. Odin's spell may have given him the physical form of an Asgardian (Æsir) but they're only a few times more resilient than the average human. As a [Frost-Giant hybrid](http://marvel.wikia.com/Frost_Giants) his tolerance to heat might even be *lower* than that of the average Asgardian.

Without his [forcefield](http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11111/111115588/3367975-loki+6.jpg) to protect him (and we've seen no evidence that he has this power in the movie universe), Loki's **physical** strength would be utterly inadequate to protect him from either the [heat or percussive effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_nuclear_explosions) of a nuclear weapon.

That said, his enhanced physique, super-healing and superhuman immune system would probably protect him from the effects of radiation poisoning if he was *outside* the immediate blast zone.

Comment: Puny God indeed!

Comment: "and we've seen no evidence that he has this power in the movie universe". I have a feeling that this is not a valid argument when dealing with The Trickster...

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla - I think we can be reasonably sure that he'd have used that ability when fighting the Hulk.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, a nuclear weapon would kill Loki.

**(This answer includes spoilers from Thor and Thor 2)**

In *Thor*, Odin tells Loki that they are not Gods. He said that they will die just like any other being, only that they live longer than humans/mortals.

In *Thor 2: The Dark World*

> Frigga, Thor and Loki's mother, was killed by a simple stab wound while she was defending Jane.

Also, if Thor, Lady Sif, and Fandral could easily kill the Frost Giants in *Thor* with weapons like Mjolnir and swords, a nuclear missile would be able to kill Loki.

Comment: Mjolnir is generally described as an "omega class" weapon and the swords you see the Asgardians using aren't merely bits of polished metal but highly technological weapons that are merely *shaped* to look like swords and axes.

Comment: That is a very good point. I didn't take into account the strength of Asgardian weapons as I should have.