# Gambit killing Wolverine?

Tags: marvel, x-men

As far as my research has turned up, and given I'm not very good at research, Gambit is the only mutant to kill Wolverine, and him not be able to regenerate. I was wondering if there was another instance, or another generation of X-men that this has happened?

Answer (score 5):

#### Unless there was a major shift in the Marvel Universe (which their soft reboot may allow since Wolverine is supposed to be weaker than he was previously) Gambit has no chance of effectively killing Wolverine.

- Previously, Wolverine's powers of regeneration were so great he could recover from almost any injury which didn't completely atomize his entire physical structure.
- Gambit's mutant power allows him to energize normal matter causing it to explode. It takes some time for Gambit's power to energize matter so even if he could affect Wolverine's skeleton he wouldn't just sit still and allow Gambit to use his powers. Wolverine's fighting ability in the past should make him easily the equal of Gambit.
- If Wolverine's skeleton were still coated with Adamantium, it would be beyond Gambit's power to affect. Adamantium isn't normal matter and is completely proof against almost all mutant powers except those which can alter reality (Franklin Richards), alter sub-molecular structures (the Phoenix Force) or Omega-level magnetic powers (such as Magneto's).

[image]

- This graphic indicates Gambit believes his power could affect Wolverine but we have no knowledge if he has ever tried to use his power on Adamantium before. If canon is to be believe, Wolverine would be unaffected unless Gambit were able to penetrate Wolverine's body with a piece of metal affected by his power.

#### See Also:

- **[Could Wolverine survive a nuclear bomb?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/13413/2765)**
- **[How to kill Wolverine?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/14364/2765)**

Comment: I like your answer but doesn't your image contradict it?  Wolverines claws are glowing like they are charged and you can see it spreading inside him. This means this is proof it would work as the bones are not organic.  Nevertheless, Woverine might be able to survive though his skeleton might not.

Comment: Glowing and exploding are two entirely different things. By Marvel canon, Adamantium cannot be affect by anything unable to affect the underlying matrix of the material. Adamantium IS INDESTRUCTIBLE (except under the right conditions) which Gambit is NOT one of them. Making it glow may have been all he was able to do. Even he doesn't know for certain.

Comment: "I got the power to charge up **anything**....long as its not organic....I'm heating 'em up as we speak". He doesn't sound unsure even if he is bluffing.  He may be wrong and the intent of the author of this particular comic might not jive with canon. I just mean this scene definitely seems to imply he can.  Oh and glow != explode but glow != unaffected/"completely proof".  As I said though, I think you are right but this scene muddies the waters.

Comment: But this is likely where the OP got the idea Gambit COULD affect Adamantium. And given the quality of the writers today who are unfamiliar with previous continuity, I would not be surprised if the writer was completely unfamiliar with both characters...

Comment: Wonderful answer. :-)