# Wolverine's regeneration capabilities

Tags: marvel, wolverine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much of Wolverine has to be left to heal?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12486/how-much-of-wolverine-has-to-be-left-to-heal)

If someone were to cut off a limb of Wolverine using a weapon sharp enough to cut Adamantium, would the limb regenerate completely, as in regrowing the limb?  Or would the regeneration just heal the skin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers and discussions [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14347/how-to-kill-wolverine), [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12486/how-much-of-wolverine-has-to-be-left-to-heal), and a number of other questions already discuss the limits of his healing powers.

Wolverine has had his bone claws broken on a number of occasions and they've grown back just fine.

As it stands, though, [the only weapon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/14366/5184) powerful enough to sever one of his adamantium covered limbs is also able to block his healing power and kill him.

Comment: The Muramasa Blade cannot sever or break any of Wolverine's adamantium bones. They are unbreakable, period. That is the nature of adamantium. The weapon, however, in the hands of a skilled swordsman could sever his vertabra. They may be covered in adamantium, but they are still separate bone structures. With the anti-healing properties of the blade he would die from such an injury. The blade is resistant to adamantium weapons but cannot destroy them either.