# Wolverine and his Adamantium bones

Tags: wolverine, marvel, adamantium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to kill Wolverine?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14347/how-to-kill-wolverine)

Weapon X or The Wolverine, in an experiment underwent injection of adamantium into his body that covered up his skeletal. This made him kind of immortal. But whenever his flesh gets wounded how is he able to recover up? For example if a hit is possible directly to his heart or any other vital organs, wouldn't he die ?

Comment: STP, it is *well known* that Logan's immortality is due to his innate healing. That's why I voted to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

His mutant power is a supercharged [healing factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_%28comics%29#Powers_and_abilities).

His adamantium bones only exist in his skeleton because they were placed there, and the reason he was chosen to receive the skeleton is that his healing factor would enable him to survive the procedure.

There are tons of questions and answers on this site already that address the extent of his ability and that answer your question, plus resources all over the web if you care to learn more.  In short, however, a direct hit to a vital organ is no problem for his healing ability whatsoever.  [As long as he has a single cell left alive from which to regenerate, he can survive it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12486/how-much-of-wolverine-has-to-be-left-to-heal/12580#12580).

Comment: well I just am not sure about your last sentence. I think that decapitation would do the thick..

Comment: He was decapitated in the Ultimate universe, and lived. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Wolverine has a healing factor that will allow him to regenerate from extreme damage. The amount of damage he can take was discussed in this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12486/4193) and how to kill him was discussed [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14347/4193)